# Ajax Submit in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I am using a CActive Form and, earlier i was having a normal submit button. Then I changed it to an Ajax Button like as follows,

```
CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Continue',CController::createUrl('//shop/order/create&store=true'),array('type'=>'POST'));
```

This goes to the url when u refresh the page. But i want it to go to the page without page refresh. Any idea how do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [The documentation is pretty straightforward.](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#ajaxSubmitButton-detail)

Comment: ok... according to the documentation im giving a label and a url. But it doesnt work like that. I just wanna post the values and redirect back to the same page without a page refresh.

Comment: There is no page redirection involved, I'm not entirely sure that you understand what AJAX is.

Comment: ok... see with the above code, it refreshes the page. Forget about ajax... Is there any way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: You must have a javascript error, otherwise it would not submit with page refresh.

Comment: okay ill check..sorry about my ignorance..no time really to go through the documentation..im new to ajax, jquery and all that....

Comment: No problems, but you really should read at least the basics.

Answer (score 1):

try this, with some ajax success functionallity...

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('BottonLabel',
                             Yii::app()->createUrl('your/url',array('calltype' => 'system')),
                             array('type' => 'POST',
                             'cache' => true or false,
                             'success' => 'js:function(data) {yourJSfunction(data)}'),
                             array('id' => 'the_id'));
```

or follow this link to the class-reference for yii
[ajaxSubmitButton](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#ajaxSubmitButton-detail)

Comment: I dnt wanna use the success functionality. I just want to post the values within the form and redirect it to the same page without the page refresh.

Comment: thats what it does! the button posts an ajax request and the returning data will be available at the success function. the page will not be refreshed...

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
array('contoller_name/action','ajax'=>'somevalue'));
//In your case
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Continue',array('contoller_name/action','ajax'=>'yw0'));
```

Just keep in mind that you are obviously setting auto created widget ids as params (yw0). You should assign your own ids to widgets, otherwise another widget could have the same id and that can be hard to debug..

Comment: I tried using this. But the values within the form did not get posted